# Git ignore and don't track merged remote files

Tags: git, merge

My terminology may be a bit messed up.

I have 2 repos. Let's call the one Parent and the other Child. Child is dependent on Parent to work.

I allow Child to track Parent's updates through `git remote add parent parent@git`.

In Child I setup .gitattributes merge=ours for certain files that may be common like readme.md so that when I merge Parent to Child, Child's readme remains intact. When I do the merge into Child some additional files get added which are excluded from the Child repo through .gitignore.

Everything seems to work ok until I make changes to Parent and merge into Child. **Suddenly child will start tracking newly added files to Parent**. Also I have an issue where **if I delete one of the Parent files inside my local copy of Child I cant force the merge again** to get Parent's latest files?

I realise this whole thing may be a bit whack but I really need to get it to work as sub modules dont cut it, 1 repo + multiple branches completely fails & building modules/packages also has it's challenges.

Comment: 1. .gitignore work only on `git status` and alike level. That is, if some otherwise ignored files were added into a commit, then they will stay there, no exclusion]

Comment: Likely it would be better if you tell more about the task you're trying to solve, maybe with some real examples of both repositories current and desired structures.

Comment: @user3159253 Banking application built in Laravel. Business wants us to re-use this platform across multiple projects with different styling. When the "core" updates all projects must update but their styling must stay intact. The V of MVC can be drastically different between projects. MC always remains the same.

Comment: @user3159253 if the files will now not be ignored because they've been commited is there not a way during merge to prevent the tracking? Like a "silent" merge so that the Child doesn't track Parent commits?

Comment: Well, you could do the merges with `--no-commit` flag and then drop excessive files from resulting merges before commit. Maybe you need [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or [git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above question is not possible to achieve. As mentioned by @user3159253 the files will start being tracked. There is also another problem where if files are deleted on your local version you cannot get Git to force "refresh" them as it understands the merge to be up-to-date.